# Why do paragraphs become a single long line when using \colorbox?

Tags: color, highlighting

[image]

As shown in the image above, when highlighting text with color, we lose the paragraph format and all text goes to a single line. If the paragraph is long enough, the rest of text will even go beyond margins. How can I solve this and get the text to be in the normal format (i.e., actual paragraph) but highlighted?My source code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\Large
\colorbox{SkyBlue}{The text in colored box overlaps with neighboring column as seen here}   

\normalsize
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\colorbox` is like `\mbox` and , as documented, is a horizontal  mode box.

Comment: see for example the soul package for highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LaTeX use the `soul` package (load `xcolor` before `soul`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \hl{The text in colored box overlaps with neighboring column as seen here}
  \blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is super easy in ConTeXt MKIV.

```
% https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/can-i-borrow-your-highlighter-please/
\definebar
  [highlight]
  [order=background,
   rulethickness=2.5,
   offset=1.25,
   continue=yes,
   color=yellow]

\starttext

\startcolumns[n=2]
  \highlight{The text in colored box overlaps with neighboring column as seen here}
  \input lorem
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]